# Mulivariate Probability Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

Let **X** and **Y** have the joint probability density function given by:

f(x,y)=$\frac{1}{4}exp{\frac{-(x+y)}{2}}$, x>0 and y>0

(a) Find Pr(x<1,y>1)

(b) Find Pr(y<$x^2$)

This is how I tackled (a):

Pr(x<1,y>1)=$\int\int exp{\frac{-(x+y)}{2}}$ dydx where $0<x<1$ and $0<y<\infty$. My problem is with the interdependency of the two variables. Are they dependent or independent?

For (b), I had no clue at all. Someone should please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

Both are just double integrals. (a) should be
$$\int_0^1 \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{4}e^{-(x+y)/2} \, dy \, dx$$
Along similar line of reasoning, (b) should be
$$\int_0^\infty \int_0^{x^2} \frac{1}{4}e^{-(x+y)/2} \, dy \, dx$$

Comment: That was the quickest response ever. Many thanks for assisting me on that. I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

We address your dependence/independence problem, but point out that one does not need to do it to set up and evaluate the integrals.

To find the marginal density of $X$, "integrate out" $y$. We get $f_X(x)$, where $f_X(x)=0$ for $x\le 0$, and $f_X(x)=\frac{1}{2}e^{-x/2}$ for $x\gt 0$.

Similarly, we find the marginal density $f_Y(y)$ of $Y$.

Note that the given joint density function is $f_X(x)f_Y(y)$. So $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

**Remark:** In general, if the joint density of $X$ and $Y$  **factors** as a product of a density function $g(x)$ and a density function $h(y)$, then $X$ and $Y$ are independent. We have to be careful about applying this, for the factorization must apply to *full* joint density, including the parts where the joint density is $0$.

So for example the function $f(x,y)$ which is $8xy$ for $0\le x\le y\le 1$ and $0$ elsewhere is not the joint density function of a pair of independent random variables. The problem is that the joint density "lives" on a triangle, not a rectangle.  The full joint density does not factor.

Comment: @Adre Nicholas... this definitely helps. Many thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: You are welcome. I did not address your main technical question, since that was well taken care of.

Comment: Nicholas... I realised that. But what answer did you get for problem (b) Pr(y<$x^2$)? I had Pr(y<$x^2$)=0.561818. I want to be sure if I did the right thing. I used the same line of reasoning as suggested by @symmetricuser...

Comment: I am error-prone, but I got something that is numerically close to your answer. When you integrate the second time. you are dealing (after completing the square) with a close relative of the normal. Then I used tables, got about $0.562$.

Comment: Nicolas, thanks so much...